# Ruby Celluloid "environment"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, celluloid

I am very new to Celluloid, but I don't understand why, in my Rails app, my futures loose the current locale:

```
puts "locale OUTSIDE #{I18n.locale}"
data.map do |item|
  Celluloid::Future.new { puts "locale INSIDE #{I18n.locale}"; serialize_item(item) }
end.map(&:value)
```

basically I got something like

```
locale OUTSIDE en
locale INSIDE it
locale INSIDE it
locale INSIDE it
locale INSIDE it
locale INSIDE itlocale INSIDE it
locale INSIDE it

locale INSIDE it

locale INSIDE it
```

and when I change locale the futures keep considering my default locale :it

I feel like I am missing something basic...

Comment: Btw, what problem are you solving by using Celluloid in a Rails application? Are you using C Ruby or JRuby / Rubinius?

Comment: I am actually dirtying my hands in somewhere else code.. who was making use of futures which call external services that return localized data. Now I am dealing with locales dynamic..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Celluloid futures get executed in a separate thread pool (not a different process as some answers suggest),

`I18n.locale` value gets stored in a variable scoped to the individual thread http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/I18n%2FConfig%3Alocale :

> The only configuration value that is not global and scoped to thread is :locale. It defaults to the default_locale.

Meaning that the config you set outside of the worker threads does not apply within the worker threads.

You need to:

1. use `I18n.default_locale` if you want the config to be propagated to all worker threads in the process, OR
2. send the locale as a parameter into the future and set it (be sure to clear it again in an ensure block or funny things might happen with other celluloid actors)

Comment: Thank you @bbozo, I need to go for the second option as the locale is dynamic. However the fact that some variables are scoped to the individual thread makes me feel unconfident with Celluloid... Is there any rule of thumb or suggestions I can follow? Maybe because I am not so expert about concurrency but I think I could have never sorted it out by myself. thanks!

Comment: `Celluloid` provides access to thread locals, but `Futures` are executed in `Group::Spawner` threads, differently than for `Actor` instances. The issue is not with `Celluloid` in this case, but `I18n` which is evidently not thread-safe.

Comment: @digitalextremist, I'm not sure what you mean, I would assume that in threaded web servers you would want to keep the locale scoped to a thread, which it is. It has perhaps unexpected consequences when combining with Celluloid, but I kind of expected them because if `I18n.locale` worked in a different way, the threaded web servers wouldn't work with `I18n.locale`

Comment: Depending on `Thread` locals is not thread safe. Using concurrent data structures is, which are thread agnostic and depend on semaphores to keep mutable data in a place accessible by any thread -- sequentially. In the instance of `Celluloid`, you might be experiencing some of what you're experiencing if you're using `jRuby` because in that ruby engine, `Fibers` are actually light-weight `Thread` instances. To cheat, I would try `Rubinius` if you aren't already, versus refactor for thread safety.

Comment: @digitalextremist, as far as I can see, sending an immutable locale variable into the thread and keeping that immutable value within the thread scope is thread-safe, and there is no need for thread synchronization, afaik that's the basic idea behind the actor pattern - not mutable data structures, but sending immutable values to actor mailboxes, which is what needs to happen here under option 2).

Comment: @bbozo how `Celluloid` implements the `Actor Model` does not maintain thread locals in every case, which is why I mentioned the difference between ruby engines. In what sense is depending on thread locals thread-safe?! To some that's the exact definition of unsafe.

Comment: But yes, that's a very good point about a weak point of Celluloid, it depends on threads and fibers to do it's magic, and ruby implementations basically fall into three categories: sucks at threading (yarv), sucks at fibering (jruby), and sucks at production (rubinius) and there's all sorts of nooses a programmer can hang himself with because of that

Comment: @digitalextremist doing stuff with thread locals means other threads won't change the outcome of the execution of the current thread, it's definition of thread-safety as far as I get it - but if you want to reuse your threads then you're in trouble in same way you're in trouble if you want to reuse your processes for multiple requests and you use global variables, but we're getting out of scope and SO wants us to move to a chat, so I'll finish here

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the locale, pass it as an argument to the constructor:

```
Celluloid::Future.new(locale = I18n.locale) { puts "locale INSIDE #{locale}" }
```

I believe the block will be executed in a new process, and so your locale information will get lost.

Comment: thank you born4new ... but bbozo gave me an exhaustive answer